# Get average of array subkey until other subkey contains "xx"

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to find a way to extract an average of a subkey of several arrays (up to 80) **UNTIL** another subkey has a certain value.

The full code contains the following:

```
$element = $html->find('table',3);

    $i = 0;
    foreach($element->find('tr') as $row){
    if($i >= 2){
      $racelapno = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;
      $racelaptime = $row->find('td',1)->plaintext;
      $raceposition = $row->find('td',2)->plaintext;
      $racetyre = $row->find('td',3)->plaintext;
      $raceweather = $row->find('td',4)->plaintext;
      $racetemp = $row->find('td',5)->plaintext;
      $racehum = $row->find('td',6)->plaintext;
      $raceevent = $row->find('td',7)->plaintext;


      $racelap[$i] = Array();
      $racelap[$i][0] = $racelapno;
      $racelap[$i][1] = $racelaptime;
      $racelap[$i][2] = $raceposition;
      $racelap[$i][3] = $racetyre;
      $racelap[$i][4] = $raceweather;
      $racelap[$i][5] = $racetemp;
      $racelap[$i][6] = $racehum;
      $racelap[$i][7] = $raceevent;
    }
      $i+=1;
}
```

So I want to find the average of all `$racetemp` in the different arrays until an array returns "pit" on `$raceevent`.

Browsing on here I have found a way to find the average of all arrays which looks as followed:

```
$counter = 0;
$total = 0;
foreach($racelap as $row) {
    $counter++;
    $total += $row['5'];
}
$avgracetemp = $total / $counter;
```

But now I need to add some sort of stop when `$racelap[$i][7]` contains "pit", but also continue again until it contains "pit" again.

Hope anyone can help me, it is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, in `foreach` you can just use something like:

```
if (strpos($row['7'], 'pit') !== false) {
    $counter++;
    $total += $row['5'];
}
```

Comment: I don't think it works, I've updated the main post to cover the full code involved in this. Hope you can specify where I would have to place that piece of code.

Comment: You should only change the same things in the answer: 'xx' to 'pit', $row['1'] to $row['5'], $row['2'] to $row['7']. Logic is the same.

Comment: Updated the answer according to new question.

Comment: If I add that to the _"foreach($racelap as $row)"_ (2nd block of code), the code does work but it gives me 0 as average.. so for some reason it isn't adding up.